# Unix command does not work in Tcl script

Tags: tcl

I'm new to Tcl and UNIX programming.

The following command works on the UNIX command-lines, but doesn't work in a Tcl script.

```
$ sort -b -k8  abc.txt | awk '!a[$1]++'
error out for 8 (-k8) and 1($1) is not variable
```

I'm trying to sort on Column 8 *first* and *then* pick only unique data on column 1.

I'm also trying to save data into a file.

Comment: Can you update your question with the source code of the tcl script, 4 spaces at start of line to format code block correctly.

Comment: Thanks Tian  send_unix_cmd "sort -k$sort_col  top_$host |  awk '!a[${$uni_col}]++'  "
where sort_col set to 8 and uni_col set to 1

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to escape `[]` and `$` in the string, eg:

```
send_unix_cmd "sort -k$sort_col top_$host | awk '!a\[\$$uni_col\]++' "
```

I also removed the `{}`.

Answer (score 1):

I thing for executing command in `Tcl` script you should use `exec`. And single quotes have no special meaning in `Tcl` script so it will try to expand the variable `$1`. You can try following:

```
exec sort -b -k8  abc.txt | awk {!a[$1]++} > output
```

If you don't redirect the standard output of the program, it becomes the return value of the `exec` command, so you can capture it for example:

```
set result [exec sort -b -k8  abc.txt | awk {!a[$1]++}]
```